# Calculate hits per day

Tags: java, sql, if-statement, java-8, switch-statement

I need help to implement hits per day based on the user selected package. This is what I made so far but it's not working properly:

***Entity:***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UsersModel implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "plan")
    private String plan;

    @Column(name = "plan_last_activity")
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime planLastActivity;
}
```

Code:

```
public boolean calculateClickTimes() {

    String userName = SecurityUtils.getSubject().getPrincipal().toString();
    QueryDashboardHelper queryHelper = new QueryDashboardHelper();
    UsersModel user = queryHelper.getUserByUserName(userName);

    String plan = user.getPlan(); // silver/gold/platinum/diamond
    int todayHits = user.getTradesPerDay();
    LocalDateTime lastHit = user.getPlanLastActivity();

    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    LocalDateTime tenSecondsLater = now.plusDays(1);

    long diff = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(lastHit, tenSecondsLater);

    switch(plan) {

      case "diamond":

        if(diff >= 1 && todayHits >= 20) {
            todayHits = 0;
            return true;
        }       
        break;

      case "platinum":

        if(diff >= 1 && todayHits >= 15) {
            todayHits = 0;
            return true;
        }       
        break;  

      case "gold":

        if(diff >= 1 && todayHits >= 10) {
            todayHits = 0;
            return true;
        }             
        break;  

      case "silver":

        if(diff >= 1 && todayHits >= 5) {
            // User has clicked 5 times today
            todayHits = 0;
            return true;
        }
        break;

      default:

    }

    return false;
}
```

The general idea is that users should be limited to perform hits in web page based on the selected package (silver/gold/platinum/diamond) and based on the data from the database `plan`, `tradesPerDay` and `planLastActivity` the allowed hits should be limited for the current day. 
Can you give me some advice how to implement this code properly, please?

Comment: The first and obvious mistake in the code above that the condition for a _silver_ plan is also true for all other plans, i.e `todayHits >= 5` is true for a `todayHits >= 10`, etc. So you should change cases by falling down values: case "diamond" -> case "platinum" etc.

Comment: You might want to revisit [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html).

Comment: I updated the code. Can you give me some more advice how to implement this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it on the database level:

```
create table users (
    id bigint primary key ,
    plan character varying,
    trades_today int
);

insert into users (id, plan, trades_today)
values (1, 'diamond', 15),
       (2, 'silver', 5),
       (3, 'gold', 0);

with packages(package_type, max_hits) as (
    values ('diamond', 20),
           ('platinum', 15),
           ('gold', 10),
           ('silver', 5)
)

select u.id, trades_today < p.max_hits
from users u
inner join packages p on u.plan = p.package_type;
```

This results in:

```
+--+--------+
|id|?column?|
+--+--------+
|1 |true    |
|2 |false   |
|3 |true    |
+--+--------+
```

Every time a hit is done, the counter is increased. The counter is reset every midnight

Answer (score 2):

it's a suggestion mechanism skeleton that can give you idea about using Spring aspect to handle this kind of scenarios

**Create an annotation e.g TrackHit:**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface TrackHit{
    
}
```

**and create an aspect**

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class HitTrackerAspect {
    private final HitTrackerService hitTrackerService;

    public HitTrackerAspect(HitTrackerService hitTrackerService) {
        this.hitTrackerService = hitTrackerService;
    }
    
    // annotation package also should provided if present e.g @annotation(x.y.TrackHit)
    @Around(value = "@annotation(TrackHit)")
    public Object TrackUserHit(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature();
        Method method = signature.getMethod();
        TrackHit trackHit = method.getAnnotation(TrackHit.class);
        if(trackHit !=null){
            String userName = SecurityUtils.getSubject().getPrincipal().toString();
            if (userName!=null) {
                // hitTrack service is used to check user plan , logic implemented inside isUserAllowed method 
                // of HitTrackerService 
                boolean allowed = hitTrackerService.isUserAllowed(userName)
                if(allowed){
                    return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in services that need to be invoked by user add TrackHit annotation on it , aspect will check if allowed will proceed

e.g calling latest price limited by aspect login and should checked before invoked

```
@Service
public class PriceInquiryService {
    
    @TrackHit
    public long getLatestPrice(Long itemCode){
        // latest price logic here 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But what algorithm can you propose to limit the hits per day?

Comment: using a hit history table,  user => hit timestamp maping, each time i will insert a new record in it inside sample aspect method i provided above each time api called by user. when i want to check i will call a aggregate query of count that is limited by user id and time between start of today time and end time of today mean today 00:00 to today 23:59 then check my plan according to number of hit count of a user during latest 24 hours